# How can I bind transition name property in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, binding

Can I bind transition name property in vuejs?

```
<transition-group
   :name="{ transactionAnimation: isActive }"
   tag="tbody"
   class="list-group"
>
//.... some code
</transition-group>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this if it is just about the `name`:

```
<transition-group
   :name="isActive ? 'transactionAnimation' : null"
   tag="tbody"
   class="list-group"
>
//.... some code
</transition-group>
```